# Is it possible to have a virtualenvwrapper run Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenvwrapper

I use Python v2.7.10 on my computer and I prefer to use it for developing. I want to download a program online that I downloaded that supposedly misbehaves when running anything other than Python3.

I have seen other questions in this site that suggest to download Python3 globally and then modify virtualenvwrapper to use it, but I prefer to isolate my environments, the whole point for me to use this virtual environment.

Is there a way that I can install Python3 and have it isolated solely to that environment?

Comment: install Python3 and use the `-p` option to `mkvirtualenv` to specify which python version you want to use in your new `venv` or install anaconda with python 3.x

Comment: @user3100115 The first suggestion you gave other users in this site already suggested in other questions, but I prefer not to install Python 3 globally, the reason I posted this question. The second suggestion you gave, anaconda, exactly filled what I required. If you post it as an answer, I will choose it as the answer for this question.